# Best practices for data manipulation to use in admin dashboard application?

Tags: web-development, web-applications, data, web-api

I am trying to create admin dashboard to track sales and inventory. Using React front end and Django rest backend API.

Right now I am pulling sales and would like to make some charts.

What's the practice here?

Do I pull raw data then manipulate data in React? With some package?

Do I manipulate in backend? Do I creati api point like remote function and then backend manipulates data on the fly? Or Do I create database table to hold data for each report (sales last 7 days... etc)?

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

My take in data reporting is that you want your data backend to be scalable and flexible for future needs, not just the moment. Any time you aggregate data (for example taking individual transaction as a row of data at the day level) you shift the computational cost to your servers (which is finite but cost effective), the tradeoff is that you can no longer "reuse" the code if the user suddenly wants the ability to see individual transactions if they are observing daily trends.

So to answer your question

> What is the best practice?

There is no "best" practice one-size-fits-all, it all boils down to who is your audience and how sophisticated they are in using the "admin dashboard application" you are developing. Unless you are a one-man-shop you must have a data warehouse team that maintains the back-end of things in terms of the physical hardware (or administering cloud services) and at the same time, business analyst teams who will actually translate data and business intelligence (the charts and graphs) to actionable business decisions.

If there is a step 1 for you, I believe you have put the cart before the horse. ***Talk to your team for their input before you start creating stuff*** - their experience can save you time and frustration when it turns out what they want is simpler than what you envisioned.